# Dependency Injection with items that need to be created/disposed per use

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, factory-pattern

What is the proper way to handle DI for dependencies that need to be created/disposed everytime they are used? That is to say: dependencies that should only ever be used in the context of a using statement...

```
public void Foo()
{
    IUnityContainer myContainer = GetContainer();
    using (IDataStore store = myContainer.Resolve<IDataStore>())
    {
        //Do work...
    }
}
```

**My Specific Problem**

My app's `DbContext` implements an `IDataStore` interface. Because DbContext is not thread safe, and my business classes need to be, my business classes need to create a new `IDataStore` instance any time they need to interact with the database.

I've tried 3 different approaches, but they all have problems:

1. Use a static IUnityContainer (like a singleton) that every business object has access to, and resolve a new instance of `IDataStore` whenever it is needed. As an added bonus, this IUnityContainer can be used in static methods where DI is usually not possible.
2. Dependency inject my IUnityContainer into every business class, and resolve a new instance of `IDataStore` whenever it is needed.
3. Dependency inject my IDataStore into every business class.

With **Approach 1**, everything works. But this is apparently an anti-pattern. There are a lot of explicit `.Resolve<IDataStore>()` calls happening in the business code. It also means that every business object is stuck using the same IUnityContainer, although right now that doesn't seem to be an issue.

With **Approach 2** All of my business classes need to pass around the same IUnityContainer whenever they create instances of other business classes. It is also apparently considered a bad practice to DI you IoC container.

With **Approach 3**, I cannot create new instances of IDataStore from within the class. If I use `using` blocks, this means that I can only use the IDataStore once (because it will get disposed). If I don't use `using` blocks, the IDataStore instance will likly be created on one thread then used on another (causing threading issues for the DbContext). Not only that, but now each of my business classes now need to have a IDataStore passed to them in their constructors (or have a property set). This makes it even MORE likely that threading issues will occur, because many business classes instantiate other business objects and must do so using their own IDataStore.

To me, it seems that approach 1 is the best of these three, it allows me to create a new instance of IDataStore every time I resolve it. But if this is a bad practice, I want to know why. Is there a better approach to do this?

**Update**

I'm thinking now that I may need a IDataStoreFactory interface that is dependency injected instead of the IDataStore itself. This would mean that the concrete Factory class would have to instantiate a specific implementation of IDataStore...

```
public Interface IDataStoreFactory
{
    IDataStore CreateNew();
}

public class MyDbContextFactory: IDataStoreFactory
{
    public IDataStore CreateNew()
    {
        return new MyDbContext();
    }
}
```

And then in my other class...

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private IDataStoreFactory factory;

    public SomeClass(IDataStoreFactory factory)
    {
       this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        using (IDataStore store = factory.CreateNew())
        {
           //Do work...
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a valid approach to solve this problem, or is it also a bad practice? I haven't really used DI (or factories) before, so I want to make sure that I'm not doing something that is going to bite me down the road.

Answer (score 3):

Dependency Injection is essentially a set of patterns related to the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). As Robert C. Martin explains in [APPP, chapter 11](http://amzn.to/19W4JHk): "clients [...] own the abstract interfaces". What this means is that an interface is defined by what the client *needs*, not by what any particular implementation provides.

Specifically, it means that interfaces ought never to derive from `IDisposable`, because clients never need their dependencies to be disposable; that concern is exclusively related to a concrete implementation.

The point here is that `IDataStore` should not derive from `IDisposable`. Instead, it should only expose methods that the client *needs*. Let's call such a method `Bar`.

Any client should be able to use any implementation of `IDataStore`:

```
var baz = this.store.Bar(qux);
```

where `this.store` is an instance of `IDataStore`.

How do you deal with objects that need disposal, then?

You use a [Decoraptor](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/08/24/decoraptor). Specifically, you create an implementation of `IDataStore` that takes care of the lifetime management of your database context:

```
public class DataStoraptor : IDataStore
{
    public IBaz Bar(IQuz qux)
    {
        using (var ctx = MyDbContext())
        {
            return ctx.Bar(qux);
        }
    }
}
```

This simplified example assumes that `IDataStore` only defines a single member called `Bar`, but I'm sure you can extrapolate from the example.

This example has the drawback that it creates a new `MyDbContext` for every method call. This is safe, but perhaps not the most efficient use of resources. If, for example, you have several clients using `IDataStore` in the same thread, you may want to be able to reuse a single instance of `MyDbContext` in that thread. In that case, you can use [a variation of Decoraptor that takes an Abstract Factory as a dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/08/25/decommissioning-decoraptors). You can then implement that Abstract Factory in such a way that it returns instances that are scoped to a particular thread (or other sort of scope).

That variation is much more complicated, though, so make sure you need it before adding that complexity. *Measure* performance, and stick to the simpler implementation shown above as long as performance is good enough.

Comment: In my case, my IDataStore has a method "GetAll<T>()" that returns "IQuerable<T>()". This is so that objects using the IDataStore can take advantage of defered-exection. Because of this, I cannot dispose of the object in the same way as your "Bar" example as the actual DbContext would have been disposed before the query was actully executed.

Comment: @NuclearProgrammer Well, [`IQueryable<T>` has nothing to do with Dependency Inversion](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/26/IQueryableTisTightCoupling). It doesn't expose what the client *needs*, but what the implementation provides, which is exactly the opposite of the DIP.

Comment: Would it be better to create a IDbContextFactory instead of a IDataStoreFactory, and just code using the base class DbContext instead of IDataStore? I need to be able to take advantange of defered-exection and at the same time swap out where the data is coming from in my Unit Tests.

Comment: @NuclearProgrammer What does *better* mean? From the perspective of the DIP: *no*, they are all leaky abstractions.

Comment: I guess I'm not clear on how to abstract my DbContext. I want to swap out my DataContext for Unit Tests, and I need to be able to take advantage of defered-exection.